# How To Remap This Clouds Shader To Wrap Around Volume Cube Made Into Sphere?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders

today I am making a procedural Earth-like planet in Geometry Nodes, but I am deviating from the tutorial to add a nice looking cloud layer that works in Eevee. I have run into a snag as to how it maps the shader, and I can only get the clouds to appear in the upper half of the volume cube. I'm including the blend, thankfully it's a small file size, as the Cloud material is very complex and I can't capture it in a screenshot. If I were to make an educated guess, I'd say it looks like there is a cut-off in the coordinates at the z-axis 0 point, as it is cutting off right at the ground level. I don't know, math is where I always get hung up and have to ask for help. Thank you for your continued assistance.

Edit: I found the solution in the Clouds shader, there is a Flat Mask and I just had to adjust the color ramps on it to spread the Clouds across the full sphere!

Edit: To avoid having to start a whole other topic, I've run into another issue. I'm trying to use my attribute "mountains" (The mountains) to change the roughness map. I managed to make it work for the bump map, but every combination of Math node settings, Mix Color node settings, and Mix node settings seems to override one of the maps or removes the specularity of one of the maps altogether. I'm still new to understanding attributes and the like, but I'm perplexed why it was straightforward for the bump but not for the roughness.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the Clouds shader, there is a *Flat Mask* and I just had to adjust the color ramps on it to spread the Clouds across the full sphere. Now I'm just stuck figuring out how to do the roughness map.